# How to use netplan to do the same as was being done using iptables?

Tags: iptables, netplan

I am setting up a new server with 18.04 based on instructions written for 14.04. I have got as far as these steps:

```
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j REDIRECT -p tcp --destination-port 80 --to-ports 8080
/sbin/iptables-save
# To save permanently (reset-persistent):
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
# Modify in /etc/network/interfaces
# Add this line:
    pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules    
# As below:

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
    pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules

# The primary network interface
auto eth0 eth1
iface eth0 inet static
        address XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway XXX.XXX.XX.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 XXX.XXX.0.3
iface eth1 inet static
        address XX.XXX.67.47
        netmask 255.255.0.0
```

But it turns out that 18.04 does things a different way, using something called netplan.

I have found questions and answers related to how to revert back to how things were done in 14.04, but I am wondering whether it is better to do the same thing the new way.

How can I do what is being done the old way using netplan?

Comment: As you can probably tell from my question, I don't really know what I'm doing. This may have already been asked, but if there is already such a question, I don't have the knowledge to find it.

Comment: A good reference to look at for help is https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: @heynnema Thanks. I've already looked at that, but as i don't know what these steps do, I can't translate into netplan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netplan does not support hook scripts:

https://netplan.io/faq#use-pre-up-post-up-etc-hook-scripts

The workaround is to use networkd-dispatcher. The above FAQ gives an example on how to do it.

The following is an example of using networkd-dispatcher to run existing ifup hooks via a script installed in /etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/50-ifup-hooks:

```
#!/bin/sh

for d in up post-up; do
    hookdir=/etc/network/if-${d}.d
    [ -e $hookdir ] && /bin/run-parts $hookdir
done
exit 0
```

Similarly, here is an example of an ifdown hook installed in /etc/networkd-dispatcher/off.d/50-ifdown-hooks:

```
#!/bin/sh

for d in down post-down; do
    hookdir=/etc/network/if-${d}.d
    [ -e $hookdir ] && /bin/run-parts $hookdir
done
exit 0
```

Comment: https://netplan.io/faq says that these hooks run *asynchronously*, i.e. they do not prevent netplan from advancing to the next state. Isn't that completely unacceptable for security, as your link could go up before your iptables firewall is in place?